# How to confirm which environment.ts file an Angular app ends up using?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I'm trying to understand how I can *confirm* which `environment.ts` (or `environment.<env>.ts`) file an Angular app is using.

In -my- scenario, I'm building the app in a Docker image and then running that image. But, even if I "terminal" into a "node docker image instance" and then manually build the image, I'm not sure what to look for because it looks like all the files are merged into a few new ones.

I do have an `angular.json` and `package.json` files in the root of the repo.

Snippet from my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-web-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build:development": "ng build --configuration=devProduction",
    "build:production": "ng build --configuration=production"
  },
  ...
```

Here's what I'm doing (taken from my Docker file):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

npm run build
```

All of these files end up getting 'built' into `/app/dist`. The Docker file ends up just Nginx where those files from `/app/dist` and copied over to `/usr/share/nginx/html` (to light up a webserver to serve the Angular app).

So I'm *guessing* that my `npm run build` step needs some extra logic here.

### Edit

(instead of answering because it's a note, more than an answer)

I kept wondering *why* my config settings (from `environment.prod.ts`) was getting built into the build assets.

It was because in the `angular.json` file, I had this:

[image]

So `npm run build` was actually doing the 'default' build .. it was just that someone put PROD instead of DEV, in there.

Comment: Files can be exported manually by pointing to a path in angular.json
  "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputPath: ''some_path'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **angular.json** file you should have configurations defined, together with file replacements for env files (or any other, if you define them). And of course, you can define your own configs: *stage, testing, etc*.

```json
"dev": {
  "optimization": false,
  "outputHashing": "none",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": false,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": false,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
    }
  ]
},
"production": {
  "optimization": true,
  "outputHashing": "all",
  "sourceMap": false,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "aot": true,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ]
},
```

In a **package.json** you can then define what configuration to use in which build script.

```json
"build:dev": "npm run build -- -c dev",
"build:prod": "npm run build -- -c production",
```

In your case, if you are running just `npm run build` I'm positive you are running it in **dev configuration**.

Comment: is there any way _post running_ `npm run build` to see where those values from the `environment.ts` file ended up?

Comment: After the build, I don't think so. Env variables will be replaced, so you would need to find their values within js build

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason,I had created this script to detect environment. You may have to change something to use in your project.

https://github.com/indraraj26/ng-show-environment-config